# How to Customize Data FullcalendarBundle from a SUBMIT form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, fullcalendar

i have added a select form above the FullCalendar to select an user and show his events

the question is how to load the events of the user selected in the calendar

THIS is some of code:

**In Calender.html.twig**

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
            height: 'parent',
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
            locale: 'fr',
            header: {
                left: 'prev, next, today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
            },
            businessHours: {
                start: '09:00',
                end: '18:00',
                dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            },
            height: "auto",
            contentHeight: "auto",
            lazyFetching: true,
            navLinks: true,
            selectable: true,
            editable: true,
            eventDurationEditable: true,
            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: "{{ path('fullcalendar_load_events') }}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  {
                        filters: {}
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

I have have changed the code to :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <select id="school_selector">
            <option value="User1">User1</option>
            <option value="User2">User2</option>
            <option value="User3">User3</option>
        </select>

        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">Calendrier des entretiens</div>
        <div class="bg-light">
            <a href="{{ path('booking_new') }}">Create new booking</a>
            {% include '@FullCalendar/Calendar/calendar.html.twig' %}

        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/locale-all.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
                height: 'parent',
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
                locale: 'fr',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev, next, today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
                },
                businessHours: {
                    start: '09:00',
                    end: '18:00',
                    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                },
                height: "auto",
                contentHeight: "auto",
                lazyFetching: true,
                navLinks: true,
                selectable: true,
                editable: true,
                eventDurationEditable: true,
                eventSources: [
                    {
                        url: "{{ path('fullcalendar_load_events') }}",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:  {
                            filters: {}
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!');
                        }
                    }
                ],
                eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
                    return ['', event.USER].indexOf($('#school_selector').val()) >= 0
                }
            });
            $('#school_selector').on('change',function(){
                $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');

            })
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**App\Enity\Event**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class Event extends \Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Entity\Event
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $User;


    /**
     * @param string $User
     */
    public function __construct($title, \DateTime $start, \DateTime $end = null,$User)
    {
        parent::__construct($title,$start,$end);
        $this->User=$User;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->User;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $User
     */
    public function setUser($User)
    {
        $this->User = $User;
    }


}
```

**App\EventListener\FullCalendarListener** ( loadEvents )

```
 public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendar)
    {

        $startDate = $calendar->getStart();
        $endDate = $calendar->getEnd();
        $filters = $calendar->getFilters();

        $bookings = $this->em->getRepository(Booking::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->andWhere('b.beginAt BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

        foreach($bookings as $booking) {

            $bookingEvent = new Event(
                $booking->getTitle(),
                $booking->getBeginAt(),
                $booking->getEndAt(),// If the end date is null or not defined, it creates a all day event
                $booking->getUser()
            );

            $bookingEvent->setUrl(
                $this->router->generate('booking_show', array(
                    'id' => $booking->getId(),
                ))
            );
            $calendar->addEvent($bookingEvent);
        }
    }
```

I HAVE TRIED this one, but nothing is display :(

Ps: The entity Event have id, begin_at, title, end_at, user
// User= Name of user

Sample event data:

```
[ 
  { title: 'Event1', start: '2019-03-01', end: '2019-03-02', User: 'User1', }, 
  { title: 'Event2', start: '2019-03-04', end: '2019-03-05', User: 'User2', }, 
]
```

Comment: Implement your event source using this pattern: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . Then your function can get the currently selected user ID from the select box and send the value to the server as part of the ajax request. The server will then filter the returned data according to the user ID. The other part of this is that you need to handle the "change" event of the select box using JavaScript, and in that event handler you just run the "refetchEvents" method of fullCalendar to make it reload the data using the new value. Give that idea a try and post code if you get stuck.

Comment: For example, i'm admin and i want select an user by his name and show all his event in calendar

Comment: Ok so read my last comment, and implement each part of my suggestion. You can easily research each element separately online if you don't know how to do it (e.g. google [javascript select handle change event example](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=CwN5XIuvH4uqUPr0sOAK&q=javascript+select+handle+change+event+example&oq=javascript+select+handle+change+event+example&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.9881.11920..12035...2.0..0.180.1347.1j9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i21.KjulP0Bzw48) and you'll get plenty of material to help you with that part).

Comment: Ok ADyson, i will try and return to you, thank you

Comment: sorry, I couldn't..

Comment: couldn't what, exactly? How far did you get? Surely you managed _something_? If you'd like help with what you've done so far please show us, and also explain what goes wrong and/or what errors you see in the console.

Comment: I have edited my answer look update 1

Comment: that isn't the pattern I described at all, but ok, it's a reasonable approach I think - well done. The missing piece of the jigsaw here is giving me a sample of your events JSON data, so I can see why it might not be working. Without seeing the data I can't tell if you're making the right comparison in the eventRender function.

Comment: P.S. I just noticed you said "The entity Event have id, begin_at, title, end_at, user". Fullcalendar doesn't recognise `begin_at` or `end_at`. It will treat them as custom properties. It will not use them to know where to place the event on the calendar. As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) you must supply a `start` property and also (optionally) and `end` property containing a date in a recognised format. If fullCalendar cannot see the `start` property (or its format is not valid) then your event will never appear, regardless of any other filtering.

Comment: Thank you Adyson for your support, i have added some other files look at them

Comment: I am looking already. So two things: 1) it seems your Event class's "User" property is protected. So I'm not convinced this will get serialised to JSON - you may need to make it public instead of protected. 2) JS property names are case-sensitive. So even if "User" is serialised, `event.USER` will not match it. `event.User` should match it, if it's there. This is why I asked you to provide a sample of your JSON event data as returned by the server. Can you now do that please? Then I know exactly what data your JavaScript is trying to interact with.

Comment: Actually, I can prove the User property won't be serialised. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dab7504c1bf23f28bba7117e9265cac2bb781a58 . Whereas if you make it public, it will. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a94f0d276892ec59001d3efd61d0afa7b37e6776

Comment: [
    {
      title: 'Event1',
      start: '2019-03-01',
      end: '2019-03-02',
      User: 'User1',
    },
      {
      title: 'Event2',
      start: '2019-03-04',
      end: '2019-03-05',
      User: 'User2',
    },
]

Comment: Ok so change `event.USER` to `event.User` in your eventRender code and try again

Comment: Its works, but it's show events of all users not by one, when i select other user all data disappears

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mw7okq9v/

Comment: I have tried with event.title its work, but with event.User doesn't work ..

Comment: I can't fix "don't work", sorry. You might as well tell the doctor "I'm ill" but not tell them your symptoms. You'll need to provide some actual descriptive information from your investigation/debugging concerning your data and code. P.S. See also my comment below (in the answer) about your data sample, and also my comment earlier about the "User" property in your PHP Event class being "protected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a simple one - JavaScript property names are case-sensitive.

Therefore, `event.USER` will not match the `User` property in your data.

Change `event.USER` to `event.User` and it will work.

Simple demo:

```js
var events = [{
  title: 'Event1',
  start: '2019-03-01',
  end: '2019-03-02',
  User: 'User1'
}, {
  title: 'Event2',
  start: '2019-03-01',
  end: '2019-03-02',
  User: 'User2'
}];

events.forEach(eventRender);

function eventRender(event) {
  console.log ("Testing: " + JSON.stringify(event));
  console.log("Bad code: " + (['', event.USER].indexOf("User1") >= 0));
  console.log("Good code: " + (['', event.User].indexOf("User1") >= 0));
}
```

And here's a demo of the code in action within fullCalendar: http://jsfiddle.net/mw7okq9v/

---

One further point: Although your provided JSON data sample includes the `User` property, it's unclear whether this accurately reflects the current state of what your code is actually outputting.

In your `Event` class, you have specified this property as "protected". i.e.

```
protected $User;
```

This will prevent the property being included when the object is serialised to JSON. I think you will need to make it public:

```
public $User;
```

so that the server will output this property as part of the event JSON.

Comment: I have tried your code, it's work fine, but my case not work :(
i think he don't read the attribute User from Database

Comment: Re-read the comments above, I already explained to you the likely way to solve that. I think it is probably being read from the database, but not serialised into JSON. However, the sample data you provided to me does contain the `User` property, and has valid values. So did you actually provide me the real data being output by your code, or just some sample of how you wanted it to look?

Comment: the probleme is here, 
eventRender: function eventRender(event, element) {
                    return ['', event.User].indexOf($('#school_selector').val()) >= 0
                }

he can't read the data of event.User, and i haven't know how to fix this all of the day

Comment: I have fixed the probleme, every thing is okay, thank you Adyson for your support all of the day ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can also put your user id in the `filters` object

```
eventSources: [
    {
        url: "{{ path('fullcalendar_load_events') }}",
        type: 'POST',
        data:  {
            filters: {
                user_id: "{{ app.user.id }}",
            },
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!');
        }
    }
],
```

And retrieve the value in the `$filters` array of your listener,
then update the query to fit your needs

```
public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendar)
{
    $startDate = $calendar->getStart();
    $endDate = $calendar->getEnd();
    $filters = $calendar->getFilters();

    $bookings = $this->em->getRepository(Booking::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('booking')
        ->where('booking.beginAt BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
        ->innerJoin('booking.user', 'user')
        ->andWhere('user.id = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $filters['user_id'])
        ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();

    foreach($bookings as $booking) {

        $bookingEvent = new Event(
            $booking->getTitle(),
            $booking->getBeginAt(),
            $booking->getEndAt(),// If the end date is null or not defined, it creates a all day event
            $booking->getUser()
        );

        $bookingEvent->setUrl(
            $this->router->generate('booking_show', array(
                'id' => $booking->getId(),
            ))
        );
        $calendar->addEvent($bookingEvent);
    }
}
```